# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare with call_user_func()

Tags: php, function

I'm trying to execute a couple of tests in groups where each one is a .php file which contains two functions. The problem is that each test from a given group has a clean-up function with a same name (for example test10_cleanup, where 10 is the group number).
After execution of this code:

```
$dir = __DIR__ . "/tests/";
$tests = array_slice(scandir($dir), 2);

foreach ($tests as $test) {  
  include("{$dir}{$test}");
  $arr = get_defined_functions();

  //Weird Note: user defined functions are in reverse order
  //cleanup function is in array's first element
  call_user_func($arr["user"][1]);
  call_user_func($arr["user"][0]);

  unset($arr);
}
```

It seems that unsetting and getting again currently defined functions is not clearing the previous ones. So, is it fixable with procedural code rather than using OOP or I should go straight ahead and exec a new php process for each test file?

Comment: if you don't want to adapt the test files, I suspect you have to call a new process for every test file. perhaps your test files should have another pattern ... creating a class object with the same name as  $test or a init/test function $test and a clean_up function $test_cleanup or something

Comment: @1000Gbps: Put `ob_start();` before including the file and `ob_end_clean();`  before 'unset($arr)`.

Comment: definitely go with OOP.

Comment: Can you provide an OOP solution for this case? Thanks in advance